# accessing commit message in git hook before commit is created

Tags: git, bash

I'm having some trouble with a git hook that calls an npm script and re-adds files to my staging area before commit:

> ./.git/hooks/commit-msg

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run reset

# re-add to staging before commit
git add <filepath here...>
git add <filepath here...>

exit 0
```

The hook is running but is adding files *after* it creates a commit, so I end up with files in staging and an incorrect commit. My end goal is to perform some logic here based on the contents of the `commit message`. I'm seeing the same behavior using `prepare-commit-msg`, and the hook works fine in `pre-commit`, but that isn't an option because I need the commit message string.

If I understand correctly, this is happening because at `commit-msg` and `prepare-commit-msg` by commit checksum is already calculated and I can only manipulate the message, not the contents.

Do I have any options here other than to create a commit and do some `git reset` nonsense in my hook?

**tl;dr** How do I access the `commit message` in a git hook before git actually creates a commit?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. As you have seen, by the time the commit message is fixed ("fixed" having the sense of "no longer changeable"), the *tree* is fixed as well. Your best bet is probably to prohibit users from running `git commit` at all: have them run your own program, where you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Damn, all signs pointed to that but I was hoping I was just missing something. Thanks for the reply.